# Create control in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, foreach

I can't manage to get the values from `textboxes` that are created at run-time.

I want an user to choose something from a `checkedlistbox`, and to enter any values he wants in `textboxes` that are created at every button click.

How can I get the name of those `texboxes`? They really exist? I am a beginner and I really don't understand how they are created.

This is my code where I create `textboxes`.

```
    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 466;
        int y = 84;
        foreach (var itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            int i = 0;
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Location = new Point(x, y);
            tb.Name = "txtBox" + i++.ToString();
            Controls.Add(tb);
            y += 30;
     }
```

Comment: are you using winforms ?

Comment: also - where (then) do you need the names?

Comment: You are initialising i inside the loop

Comment: yes,I use winforms. I need to get their values,and that's why I need their names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just place the `i` outside the `foreach` and done.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    i++;
    string textBoxName = "textBox" + i.ToString();
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Location = new Point(x, y);
    //tb.Name = "txtBox" + i++.ToString(); <--Your Version
    tb.Name = textBoxName;
    //...
    //Other stuff or your codes
}
```

Comment: the OP will understand that `:D`

Comment: lol.. I see that the OP is relatively new/beginner. will think its not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than searching for exact name what you can do is have a string(fixed) which is searched for the control.

so if you find that string ( in your case which is 'textbox' ), what you can do is search for that fixed string in the name of control. if it exists then it's dynamically generated control.

```
foreach(Control c in parentControlIdOrName.Controls)
{
    if(c.GetType()==typeof(TextBox))
    {
        if(((TextBox)c).Name.indexOf("textbox")!=-1)
        {
            // do your coding here...what ever you want....
        }
    }
}
```

Haven't tested but,Hope for the best. It might work.